# Not able to submit message to Azure service bus Topic using MassTransit

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to submit a message to a Azure Service Bus Topic and it keeps complaining about

`MassTransit.ConfigurationException: The message type Contracts.ClassName entity name was already evaluated: Contracts/ClassName`

I have checked my registration and can't seem to figure out what is missing?

Here is my code for submitting a message to a `Topic`

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Message<ClassName>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("topicName");
            });
        });
        
try
   {
       await bus.Publish(new ClassName
       {
            Status = status,
            User = user,                
            });
            _logger.LogInformation($"Topic Message Sent Successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to Send Message!\n{ex.Message} to Topic");
        }
```

Registration

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
     x.AddConsumer<TestConsumer>();
     x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
     {
           cfg.ClearMessageDeserializers();
           cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer();

           cfg.Host(_busConfiguration.ServiceBus.ConnectionString);

           cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_busConfiguration.ServiceBus.QueueName, ec =>
           {
                 ec.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                 ctx.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(ec);
            });
        });
     });
```

Comment: Why are you configuring the bus twice?

Comment: Configuring twice how? Please explain?

Comment: You are using both `AddMassTransit` and `Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus` - both of those create separate bus instances. If you want to configure the message type, do so in the `AddMassTransit` configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure everything at once, the separate bus configuration is a really bad idea.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
  x.AddConsumer<TestConsumer>();

  x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
  {
    cfg.Message<ClassName>(x =>
    {
      x.SetEntityName("topicName");
    });

    cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer(isDefault: true);

    cfg.Host(_busConfiguration.ServiceBus.ConnectionString);

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_busConfiguration.ServiceBus.QueueName, ec =>
    {
          ec.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
          ec.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(ctx);
    });
  });
});
```